# Prevent from a postback and run OnClick using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to validate the TextBox and click the Button of asp.net.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" Placeholder="E-mail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" runat="server" Text="Login" />
```

And here is a jQuery code which validate TextBox and then trigger the OnClick method:

```
var al = document.getElementById('<%=lblAlert.ClientID%>');
var email = document.getElementById('<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>');
var msg = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#<%=btnLogin.ClientID%>').on('click', function (e) {
      if (email.innerText == '') {
          msg = 'Please! enter email address.';
          al.innerText = msg;
      }
      else {
          $('#<%=btnLogin.ClientID%>').click();
      }
  });
});
```

### Edit:

OnClick method is:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // some code
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem, besides, that your button is clicking itself and essentially does nothing.

Comment: @Marco I have a code-behind method `btnLogin_Click` that should run after validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cancel the click event, when needed, using `event.preventDefault()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#<%=btnLogin.ClientID%>').on('click', function (e) {
      if (email.innerText == '') {
          msg = 'Please! enter email address.';
          al.innerText = msg;
          e.preventDefault();
      }
  });
});
```

No need to call click again if validation succeeds.

Comment: I want to run `OnClick` method of Login button that I've edited in my question.

Comment: So the OnClick method is never called? Even if you comment e.preventDefault(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Since in the HTML your button is already clicked when the jquery gets called, your

```
  else {
      $('#<%=btnLogin.ClientID%>').click();
  }
```

is redundant.

Here is the thing, if you want to validate and then click, then you should use a different element as a button

If you want to use the same button (recommended) then you have to prevent the postback when the validation fails by returning false.

Simple HTML concepts

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

Will never cause a postback

Here is what I would do

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" Placeholder="E-mail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClientClick="ValidateMe()" />
<script>
var al = document.getElementById('<%=lblAlert.ClientID%>');
var msg = null;
function ValidateMe() {
  var email = document.getElementById('<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>');
      if (email.innerText == '') {
          msg = 'Please! enter email address.';
          al.innerText = msg;
          return false;
      }
      else {
          return true;
      }
}
</script>
```

Comment: it again cause the postback.

Comment: Did you remove your jquery bind to the onclick?